# Java GUI Resize form after you create it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fantasy Football Toolkit");
    frame.setContentPane(new GUI().mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(350, 475);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Above is the main method to my GUI application. I'm wondering if I can change the size of the form after this main method runs. What if I want to change the size when I click a button? The problem is that I can't access frame. This has to be possible one way or another. I have looked all over for a solution but can't find one. Thanks.

Comment: You should declare your `JFrame` as an class member. You should also place your program in the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and not make everything in the `main` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always access the top level JFrame from any component that it holds via `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(yourComponent)`.  This method returns a `Window` object, but if you are 100% sure that it's a JFrame, you can always cast it (or test it first that this is so).

Once obtained, you can always call `pack()` on it to resize it to the preferred sizes of the components that it contains. In general you will want to avoid setting sizes directly as that can lead to bugs later on when you modify your program.

Comment: When using the SwingUtilities method, I call .pack and it get a nullpointerexception

Comment: @NBreunig3: then you're likely doing it at the wrong time. This only works **after** the GUI has been rendered.

Comment: Yeah nevermind I fixed the error. Thanks for your help!